# how would i need to write a java script on keypress for Alt+2 and Alt+1?

Tags: javascript, python, bash, secure-crt

I am using secureCRT for my test execution, I would need to automate some functionalities such as to recognize keypress actions thru bash script. But i couldn;t make it possible. If there any way to create bash script for keypress please provide me a comment. Or using Javascript or Python script i can integrete with bash script.

Comment: It's certainly possible in javascript to listen for a [*keypress*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/keypress) or other [*keyboard event*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent), then inspect the related event object to see which key and meta key was pressed. Not sure about integration with bash though. There are two aspects to key events: the physical key(s) pressed and the character generated. In general it's a mess so hopefully you only need to support a subset of hosts.